# Error while executing v.rast.stats command in grass plugin in qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, grass-gis, vector

I have a vector polygon which I imported in grass. I also have a raster from which I have to extract the value. I ran `v.rast.stats` command in QGIS 2.12. The command was executed with error. The error reads:

```
DBMI-DBF driver error: ￼Error while executing: 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' Finished with error
```

Don't know what to do? Tried searching for this in gis stack exchange but it talks about scripts which I don't use.

Comment: Sometimes it also gives a warning "Cannot create column (already present). Use -c flag to update values in this column". I have no idea about flags??

Comment: I think I fixed the "BEGIN TRANSACTION" error in conjuction with the DBF driver exactly a year ago: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2014-December/071549.html - Do you have an old GRASS GIS version installed?

Comment: Thx for reply markusN, but old means which version.. I have a back up file for 2.6 but I have installed 2.12 :)

Comment: Well, the fact that the DBF driver is used instead of SQLite, this suggests that you use GRASS GIS 6 rather than 7...

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an option to include additional parameters or flags from the GRASS toolbox for the v.rast.stats tool. To specify these things, you would need to run a command from the **GRASS shell**.

From the GRASS manual for [v.rast.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.rast.stats.html), you could write something like the following in order to use the `-c` flag which forces the tool to continue regardless if uploaded column(s) exist:

```
v.rast.stats -c vector=vector_map layer=1 raster=raster_map column_prefix=enter_string
```